# How to see post install and uninstall scripts logs in the subscriber Partner Developer Org

Tags: managed-package

We are trying to get the package submitted for the Security review, and it is proving to be a massive PITA.

How can i see what is going on during my post install and uninstall script deployment? e.g. my code throws exceptions but all i get is 'Post install script failed' with no details :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a patch version which puts the entire script inside a try, and then the catch sends an email to you with the exception message. That's how we debugged ours.

Incidentally if you are preparing for security review it's possible you accidentally put the post script in a with sharing context. If you do this, the script will fail. The post install or uninstall script MUST be without sharing. Any classes or references must be either without sharing or inherited sharing.

Comment: how would you send an email from the post install script?